# Using Svyciprop to get prevalence with CI across two variables

Tags: survey

**I wanted to find the prevalence of smoking in urban and in rural area.

I used this code**
[image]

**I found this result:**

[image]

We see that it results a little different, calculating all responses a whole. How can I use svyciprop especificially for one type of response. For example, how can I get result the prevalence of smoking in only rural area or in only urban area?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like `smoking` is zero/one and `urban_rural` is either `'urban'` or `'rural'` so

```
svyciprop( ~ smoking , subset( svs1 , urban_rural == 'rural' ) )

svyciprop( ~ smoking , subset( svs1 , urban_rural == 'urban' ) )
```